# Geopandas and beautiful soup - web scraping and writing to shapefile

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, geopandas, shapefile

When using the below code I get the desired column in the shapefile with title content. But only if the shapefile has one row/feature. When running on a shapefile with more than one feature no column is written at all. Any tips/help greatly appreciated!

```
import geopandas as gpd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

gdf = gpd.read_file("Test404_PhotosMeta.shp", driver="ESRI Shapefile", encoding ="utf8")

for url in gdf['url']:
 
    response = requests.get(url)
 
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
 

for title in soup.find_all('title'):
    gdf['HTitle']=title
gdf.to_file("HTitle.shp", driver="ESRI Shapefile")
```

Comment: can you provide 3 or 4 rows of sample data from **Test404_PhotosMeta.shp** ?

Answer (score 0):

- you have not provided sample data / shape file.  So have used inbuilt shape file and constructed a *url* column for purpose of demonstration
- really this is a **pandas** question not **geopandas**
- your looping logic - only last *url* will be in `response` object
- have refactored to use `apply()` so that it is run for each row

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import geopandas as gpd
from pathlib import Path

# use included sample geodataframe
gdf = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_lowres"))
# add a url column
gdf["url"] = (
    "https://simplemaps.com/data/"
    + world.loc[~world["iso_a3"].eq("-99"), "iso_a3"].str[0:2].str.lower()
    + "-cities"
)

# utility function to get titles for a URL
def get_titles(url):
    if pd.isna(url):
        return ""

    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

    # if there are multiple titles for a row join them
    return ",".join([str(t) for t in soup.find_all("title")])


# get the titles
gdf['HTitle'] = gdf["url"].apply(get_titles)

gdf.to_file(Path.cwd().joinpath("HTitle.shp"), driver="ESRI Shapefile")
```

#### sample output

```
gpd.read_file(Path.cwd().joinpath("HTitle.shp")).drop(columns="geometry").sample(5)
```

|  | pop_est | continent | name | iso_a3 | gdp_md_est | url | HTitle |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 98 | 1281935911 | Asia | India | IND | 8.721e+06 | https://simplemaps.com/data/in-cities | India Cities Database |
| 157 | 28036829 | Asia | Yemen | YEM | 73450 | https://simplemaps.com/data/ye-cities | Yemen Cities Database |
| 129 | 11491346 | Europe | Belgium | BEL | 508600 | https://simplemaps.com/data/be-cities | Belgium Cities Database |
| 113 | 38476269 | Europe | Poland | POL | 1.052e+06 | https://simplemaps.com/data/po-cities | 404 |
| 57 | 24994885 | Africa | Cameroon | CMR | 77240 | https://simplemaps.com/data/cm-cities | Cameroon Cities Database |